# Stop nav bar 2em from top of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav bar on my website that starts on the bottom left of the page, when I scroll up I want it to stop 2em from the top of the viewport.

```
<script>
  var  mn = $(".main-nav");
  mns = "main-nav-scrolled";

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1000 ) {
      mn.addClass(mns);
    } else {
      mn.removeClass(mns);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I'm having trouble with the top = formula.  Instead of 1000 I want it to stop `2em` from the top.

Comment: `viewport()` what is it? Does this return any object? Have you defined this function anywhere? and `.height` is what? A property in the returned object or jquery method `.height()`.  **doc ready** block is missing to be noted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

var store after function! like that.

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var  mn = $(".main-nav");
    mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1000 ) {
      mn.addClass(mns);
    } else {
      mn.removeClass(mns);
    }
  });
</script>
```